# Wait until all workers are done

Tags: c#, task

So I have this kind of flow:

1. Create x worker tasks
2. Do some stuff
3. Wait until all worker tasks finished
4. Proceed

I wrote this piece of code:

```
List<Task> workerTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (Worker worker in workers)
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        worker.Start();
        worker.Dispose();
    });

    workerTasks.Add(task);
}

// Do some work here

// Wait for unfinished workers
while (workerTasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted).Count() > 0) { }

// Proceed
```

While this code works so far I feel like it isn't good practice.
Would you give me some tips how to solve this problem in a better way? Thanks!

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(workerTasks.ToArray())`? Or `Task.WhenAll(...)`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Task.WaitAll()` instead :

```
Task.WaitAll(workerTasks.ToArray() );
```

Or for async methods:

```
await Task.WhenAll(workerTasks.ToArray());
```

Or return the task to the caller:

```
return Task.WhenAll(workerTasks.ToArray());
```